Approach Clarification for Optimal Strategy Question
Here is the problem I am trying to solve: You're playing a game with a deck of 52 cards. At each stage of the game, the top card of the deck is dealt face-up. You can stop dealing at any time. If the next card is red, you win. Assuming optimal play, what is the highest probability you can achieve of being correct?
My Approach
I just have a feeling that the answer is 0.5, and I can't quite put this intuition into formal words with any semblance of logical reasoning. I know that the probability that the $i^{th}$ card is red is $\frac{1}{2}$. Perhaps this means that no matter what your strategy is, you will be capped by this probability.
Regardless, let me start a formal argument that I need your help to complete. Say we have a strategy $S$ to play this game by. We must determine the $S$ that maximizes $P($success$|S)$, where success is, of course, winning the game as per the definition of winning stated in the question.

A hint:
This is a memoryless game. That means if you are in a situation that you know that say 12 black and 11 red cards are left face down in the deck, it doesn't matter for your strategy at this point how you arrived there, all that matters are those two numbers. You always know those numbers, because you started with a deck of 26 black and 26 red cards, and you know how many cards of each color have been removed from the deck up to this point.
There is also a clear 'succession' in this game, you start with 51 cards unknown, then (if you do not stop dealing), 50, a.s.o. Games with those properties can often be analyzed backwards, that is from situations that are near the end of the game to ones slightly less near and often back to the beginning.
So start about thinking what happens if you have only one face down card. What are the possibilities? What choices do you have? Once you understand that, go back one step: What happen when you have 2 face down cards? If you do a few steps, you may see a pattern an then be able to prove that the patterns is correct via induction.
This may lead into surpising insights about best, good and not so good strategies for this game.

Thanks very much! That seems exactly right. Analyzing the simpler situation and extrapolating to higher numbers of cards in the deck makes the pattern evident.
